# Conditionally render elements based on data in functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, conditional-rendering

I have a functional component in my React app that makes an API call and gets back a response featuring two contact methods **Phone Number** and **Email** and displays them next to their respective icon.

Some responses may only have one or the other contact method or neither.

In the event that a response doesn't have a contact method listed I still want to display the icon and place '--' where the data would be.

Here's my first pass at the logic where I tried writing out a few quick ternary methods, but right now all that renders on each row is `[object Object][object Object]`

```
  let renderContactDetails = methods.map(method => {

    return (
      <div>
        {
          method.contactMethodType === "M" ? `${<span><PhoneSvg /> {method.number}</span>}` : `${<span><PhoneSvg /> -- </span>}`
        }
        {
          method.contactMethodType === "E" ? `${<span><AtSymbolSvg /> {method.emailAddress}</span>}` :  `${<span><AtSymbolSvg /> -- </span>}`
        }
      </div>
    );
  });
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need to define JavaScript inside template literals and let JSX convert the html tags for you like this:

```js
let renderContactDetails = methods.map(method => {

const number = method.contactMethodType === "M" ? `${method.number}` : `--`;
const email = method.contactMethodType === "E" ? `${method.emailAddress}` : `--`;
    
    return (
      <div>
        <span><PhoneSvg /> {number}</span>
        <span><PhoneSvg /> {email}</span>
      </div>
    );
});
```

Comment: @PedroMutter And it keeps logic out of JSX which is generally a good practice.

Answer (score 1):

You mixed up template strings with jsx syntax. Just do:

```
  let renderContactDetails = methods.map(method => {

    return (
      <div>
        {
          method.contactMethodType === "M" ? <span><PhoneSvg /> {method.number}</span> : <span><PhoneSvg /> -- </span>
        }
        {
          method.contactMethodType === "E" ? <span><AtSymbolSvg /> {method.emailAddress}</span> : <span><AtSymbolSvg /> -- </span>
        }
      </div>
    );
  });
```

And then render it.

```
return (
   {renderContactDetails}
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to wrap everything in a string, that is making your components to call `toString()` method, turning into `[object Object]`. Try doing something like this:

```
let renderContactDetails = methods.map(method => {

    return (
      <div>
        {
          method.contactMethodType === "M" ? 
            <span><PhoneSvg /> {method.number}</span>} :
            <span><PhoneSvg /> -- </span>
        }
        {
          method.contactMethodType === "E" ?
           <span><AtSymbolSvg /> {method.emailAddress}</span> :
           <span><AtSymbolSvg /> -- </span>
        }
      </div>
    );
  });
```